# Managed Repository maintaining multiple time stamped SNAPSHOT versions

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, kie-wb

I am using drools workbench 6.4.0 with wildfly server 8.1.0. I am creating a managed repository with version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

I created a project under this repository. Every time i add, modify, delete a rule and do a save and then build & deploy, under the repositories folder in wildfly server, the previous SNAPSHOT version is not purged.

This means it will keep on adding to my disk space and i am only left with manually deleting the old SNAPSHOT version. If i try and edit the repository pom.xml in workbench to add maven purge dependency plugin, my changes are not saved and it display a message "Unable to complete your request. The following exception occurred: null."

But in my local .m2 repository the previous SNAPSHOT version is overridden successfully.

I need to know is drools allowing editing the repository pom.xml so that i can tell the drools repository to purge previous SNAPSHOT version.

Thanks,
Ashish Sood.